# MySQL binlog does not show SQL statements

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, binlog

While checking the binlogs, it struck me that I cannot see any SQL statement. Here's an example:

```
$> sudo mysqlbinlog 
    --database=securities 
    --start-datetime='2015-11-26 13:00:00' 
    --stop-datetime='2015-11-26 14:00:00' 
    --base64-output=decode-rows 
    --verbose 
    mysql-bin.000011
```

and the output

```
BEGIN
/*!*/;
# at 1014869455
# at 1014869609
#151126 13:00:16 server id 1  end_log_pos 1014869680    Query   thread_id=1100645   exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1448539216/*!*/;
COMMIT
/*!*/;
# at 1014869680
#151126 13:00:18 server id 1  end_log_pos 1014869750    Query   thread_id=1100211   exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1448539218/*!*/;
BEGIN
/*!*/;
# at 1014869750
# at 1014869904
#151126 13:00:18 server id 1  end_log_pos 1014869975    Query   thread_id=1100211   exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1448539218/*!*/;
COMMIT
```

However, database *securities* is being replicated to the slaves without any trouble. Also, what do the `# at 1014869904` mean? I would have expected to see statements there.

Comment: `# at 1014869904` -- probably the byte position in the binlog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this clause:

```
--database=securities
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed reveals the statements. From the MySQL docs: _--database: List entries for just this database_, but reading on, it is said that unless the database is the default one, statements won't be shown. That's just weird.